# Serial port reads only once

Tags: c#, serial-port

The following code is called several times to read data from a serial port in response to different commands sent to an attached chip & pin terminal.
However it fails to report any further responses after the 1st command.
Although there is data there, for the following commands, is not picked up or read.

How can I fix that?

I'm using `ReadExisting` serial port property.

```
private void MySerialReader() 
{
    ip_serialport.Open();
    ip_serialport.DataReceived += serialPort_DataReceived;
    //ip_serialport.Close(); //This causes the problems
}

public string RxString;

private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
    RxString = ip_serialport.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText_RX)); //<<-- ????!!! 
}

private void DisplayText_RX(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RX_Box.Items.Add(RxString);
}
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking why calling `SerialPort.Close` immediately after registering for an event results in it not working?

Comment: HI, Apologies - the SerilPort.Close has been commented out. Initailly that caused a problem in that I was not getting any response from my serial port. Now I can only see a response to the 1st command. May be I should post the whole code? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Post it, also if you can post from where the data is comming and which format will have the data (null terminated strings? lines terminated with\n? binary data?)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use timer then you can read remaining data

```
 private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
    {
        RxString = ip_serialport.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText_RX));
    }

private void DisplayText_RX(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RX_Box.Items.Add(RxString);
if(RxString!="")
    timer.start();
}
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(serialport.isopen)//check for open 
{
    RxString = ip_serialport.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText_RX));

}
```

timer.stop();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:

```
RxString = ip_serialport.ReadExisting();
```

with:

```
RxString = ip_serialport.ReadLine();
```

solved my problem.